# Proving Fibonacci sequence by induction method

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to make a conjecture as to Fibonacci numbers which are divisible by 3 and trying to prove it by mathematical induction where the initial conditons are 0 and 1.

My problem is that I handled the basis step of induction but i was not able to write inductive step.Can you help me, please?

By the way, I found that it is divisible by 3 where F0=0 , F4=3 , F8=21 ,F12=144 ... are divisible by 3, and F0=0 is divisible by 3 is basis step.

Comment: What do you mean by "I was not able to write the inductive step"?  Were you unable to formulate the induction hypothesis, or unable to prove it?

Comment: Cf. [Pisano period](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisanoPeriod.html)

Comment: unable to prove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to say $F_{4k}$ are divisible by 3 for all $k\geq 0$ .

For the inductive step 
$F_{4k}= F_{4k-1} + F_{4k-2} = 2 F_{4k-2}+ F_{4k-3}= 3 F_{4k-3} + 2 F_{4k-4}$.

I think you can conclude from here.

Comment: Actually,i stuck in exactly in here

Comment: I have broken it using the recurrence relation defining Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Should the last expression be $3 F_{4k-3} + 2F_{4k-4}$?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Guys,thanks for your helps. I  appreciate you.